# How can we model the piezoelectric behavior of a capacitor to mechanical and thermal transients?

Tags: capacitor, piezo, reliability, ceramic

I would like to model the behavior of ceramic capacitor to thermal and mechanical stress.

We are seeing power supply fluctuations during reliability test and suspecting the ceramic capacitors' role in this.
How do I model the capacitor behavior during temperature stressing ( -50 deg to 120 deg in 20 minutes) and cyclic mechanical vibration?

[LT3065 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3065.html#product-documentation)

[Ceramic cap datasheet](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/capacitor/ceramic/mlcc/list#part_no=C3216X8R1C475K160AE&1a_dcbias%5Bt%5D=5&1a_dcbias%5Bl%5D=1&1a_dcbiasc_f%5Bt%5D=0&1a_dcbiasc_t%5Bt%5D=100&1a_dcbiasc_t%5Bl%5D=1.00E-06&_l=20&_p=1&_c=part_no-part_no&_d=0&_106=1)

[image: lt]